# Python peak detection with variable width size

Tags: python, tuples

Here is a peak detection routine which works as I want it. However, I want to make it more flexible.

```
def peak2(x,y,dp,dv):

# Define two arrays: one for the peaks and one
# for the valleys

  peaks=[]
  valleys=[]

# Create two arrays, one for x, and one for y, where each
# element of the new array # consists of three adjacent
# elements of the old array.

  xt=zip(x,x[1:],x[2:])
  yt=zip(y,y[1:],y[2:])

# Walk through these arrays, checking to see if the middle
# value of the three old elements exceeds its neighbors by
# d or more.

  idx=1
  for i,j in zip(xt,yt):
    if(j[1]-j[0]>dp and j[1]-j[2]>dp):
      peaks.append((x[idx],y[idx]))
    elif (j[0]-j[1]>dv and j[2]-j[1]>dv):
      valleys.append((x[idx],y[idx]))
    idx+=1

  return array(peaks),array(valleys)
```

As you can see, it detects a peak by comparing a value with its right and left neighbor. And if the center value is greater than both its immediate neighbors by a certain threshold, then it is considered a peak. Similar logic for finding a valley.

I want to expand it so that it compares the center value with n neighbors on each side. I will pass a parameter to the function (call it `w`), and if `w=3`, then I do something like this:

```
xt=zip(x,x[1:],x[2:])
yt=zip(y,y[1:],y[2:])
```

which is what is currently in the routine. But if `w=5`, then I want this:

```
xt=zip(x,x[1:],x[2:],x[3:],x[4:])
yt=zip(y,y[1:],y[2:],y[3:],y[4:])
```

And if `w=n`, where `n` is odd, then I want this:

```
xt=zip(x,x[1:],x[2:],...,x[n:])
yt=zip(y,y[1:],y[2:],...,y[n:])
```

So how can I build these arrays where each element contains `n` elements of other arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `range` with `slice` to build a list of the arguments and then pass them using *unpacking* (with `*`) to `zip`:

```
xt = zip(*[x[slice(i, None)] for i in xrange(n)]) # use range in Python 3
yt = zip(*[y[slice(i, None)] for i in xrange(n)])
```

In the case you may be having more than two dimensions, it may be better to build the list of slices once and then use it with `map` and `list.__getitem__` to create the new list slices:

```
slices = [slice(i, None) for i in xrange(n)]
xt = zip(*map(x.__getitem__, slices)
yt = zip(*map(y.__getitem__, slices)
zt = zip(*map(z.__getitem__, slices)
```

---

On another note, since the sizes of your list arguments are not constant and `zip` stops when the shortest sublist is exhausted (the last slice in this case), you may consider using [`itertools.izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do the shift operation on an iterator instead of a list, you can use `itertools.tee()` to create `n` shifted iterators like:

**Code:**

```
import itertools as it

def shift(an_iter, n):
    iters = it.tee(an_iter, n)
    for i in range(n):
        for _ in range(i):
            # remove the first i elements
            next(iters[i])
    return zip(*iters)
```

**Test Code:**

```
for i in shift('abcdefghij', 5):
    print(i)
```

**Results:**

```
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
('b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f')
('c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g')
('d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h')
('e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i')
('f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j')
```